# Search function on multiple rows in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-in

I'm wondering how do I add more row's on my search script to be searched.

Here's my php script:

```
<?php

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db",'user','');

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $str = $_POST["search"];
    $sth = $con->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM `players` 
 WHERE region = '$str'
");

    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth -> execute();

    if($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
        ?>
```

As you can see this:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE region = '$str'
```

I want to it to search on region and rank rows.
I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE region, rank = '$str'
```

.... it's showing 0 results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not the right way to do PDO queries. It will work, but it is vulnerable to injection. See: [Prepared statements and stored procedures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). You have to learn that first, and then worry about adding an extra column to your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE ? IN (region, `rank`)
```

This searches for the parameter in both columns `region` and `rank`.

Side notes:

- For this to properly and consistently work, both columns must be of the same datatype
- Use prepared statements! Do not concatenate variables in the query string; this is inefficient, and opens up your code to SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716)
- Starting version 8.0.2, `rank` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), hence not a good choice for a column name

Comment: You're using column names after the `IN` where you should use values.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: this does work as intented... see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36c570cf24798b53455c49e70a422197

Comment: OK, so it seems. Well, I'm trying to find it in the documentation, but looking for `IN` is not easy. 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: [IN operator in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Comment: Yes, that's it. I found it as well. Nowhere does it say you can use columns instead of values, or did I miss something? It's never too late to learn a new trick.

Comment: I tested it in my own environment, and it does indeed work. Nice!

Comment: It does work thanks.
By the way, right now it is searching for full data only, if search United or only States as a keyword it show's 0 results, but if I use the entire text like United States of America it will show the result.

Comment: It does work thanks. By the way, right now it is searching for full data only, if search United or only States as a keyword it show's 0 results, but if I use the entire text like United States of America it will show the result.

Comment: @S37uPF403: that's what `IN` does. It is essentially a shortcut for multiple `=`s. If you want pattern matching, then you need multiple `LIKE` conditions, separated by `OR`.